# How to import zig modules dynamically?

Tags: zig

I'm using zig `0.7.0.` and I'm trying to import a list of zig source files from an array. Each source file has a `main` function (whose return type is `!void`) that I would like to call. The array `module_names` is known at compile time.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
const std = @import("std");
const log = std.log;

const module_names = [_][]const u8{
    "01.zig", "02.zig", "03.zig", "04.zig", "05.zig",
};

pub fn main() void {
    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer arena.deinit();

    for (module_names) |module_name, i| {
        const module = @import(module_name); // this fails
        log.info("i {}", .{i});
        try module.main();
    }
}
```

Even if the array is known at compile time, `@import(module_name)` gives me this error:

```
./src/main.zig:13:32: error: unable to evaluate constant expression
        const module = @import(module_name);
                               ^
./src/main.zig:13:24: note: referenced here
        const module = @import(module_name);
```

I could understand the error if the array would be dynamically generated and only known at runtime, but here the `module_names` array is known at compile time. So I am a bit confused...

Alternatively, I also tried to wrap the entire `main` body in a `comptime` block:

```
pub fn main() void {
    comptime {
        var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
        defer arena.deinit();

        for (module_names) |module_name, i| {
            const module = @import(module_name); // no errors here
            log.info("i {}", .{i});
            try module.main();
        }
    }
}
```

Here `@import(module_name)` gives me no errors, but the `log.info` fails with this other error:

```
/home/jack/.zig/lib/zig/std/mutex.zig:59:87: error: unable to evaluate constant expression
            if (@cmpxchgWeak(usize, &self.state, 0, MUTEX_LOCK, .Acquire, .Monotonic) != null)
                                                                                      ^
/home/jack/.zig/lib/zig/std/mutex.zig:65:35: note: called from here
            return self.tryAcquire() orelse {
                                  ^
/home/jack/.zig/lib/zig/std/log.zig:145:60: note: called from here
            const held = std.debug.getStderrMutex().acquire();
                                                           ^
/home/jack/.zig/lib/zig/std/log.zig:222:16: note: called from here
            log(.info, scope, format, args);
               ^
./src/main.zig:26:21: note: called from here
            log.info("i {}", .{i});
```

Is this kind of dynamic import possible in zig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the kind of import you're after is possible, my understanding is that `@import` is taking a `zig` source file and turning it into a struct type. It actually seems like something that could even be done at runtime (although not using `@import`, which wants a `comptime` parameter (this is the important part for your problem).

The reason why your first example fails is that the argument you're passing, `module_name` isn't known at `comptime`, your `for` loop won't execute until your program runs.

Your instinct to solve the problem is correct, get the loop to evaluate at compile time (specifically the capture value and iterator); I think there are two things you could do fix it.

Wrapping the loop in a `comptime` block as you have done will work, but you'll need to think about what exactly it means to evaluate expressions at compile time, and if it makes sense. I think the implementation of `log` will prevent you from logging at compile time, so you'd need to collect the values you're interested in inside the loop, and log them once outside the `comptime` block.

The other way you could fix it is to force the capture values of the loop to be evaluated at compile time by unrolling the loop using an [inline for](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#inline-for):

```
pub fn main() !void {
    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer arena.deinit();

    inline for (module_names) |module_name, i| {
        const module = @import(module_name);
        log.info("i {}", .{i});
        try module.main();
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: There might be a better way of doing this, I'm comparatively new to the language =D

Comment: `inline for` is the right way to do this if you need to do runtime stuff in the loop too.

Comment: Yes, it looks like `inline for` is the right construct to use here. I also tried to build an `ArrayList` by appending `module_name` in a `comptime` block, but that didn't work. I also realized that the title of my question is a bit misleading: since I know the modules at compile time, I am not importing them dynamically at all. I still don't know if actual dynamic imports (i.e. imports at runtime) are supported in zig.

Answer (score 5):

As of [Zig 0.8.0](https://ziglang.org/download/0.8.0/release-notes.html), the operand to `@import` is [required to be a string literal](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/2206).

A Zig compiler wants to know all the possibly imported files so that it can eagerly go find them and compile them when you kick off a compilation process. The design of the language is constrained by making it possible for a fast compiler to exist.

So what can we do? I think this accomplishes the task in an equivalent manner:

```
const std = @import("std");
const log = std.log;

const modules = struct {
    pub const module_01 = @import("01.zig");
    pub const module_02 = @import("02.zig");
    pub const module_03 = @import("03.zig");
    pub const module_04 = @import("04.zig");
    pub const module_05 = @import("05.zig");
};

pub fn main() void {
    var arena = std.heap.ArenaAllocator.init(std.heap.page_allocator);
    defer arena.deinit();

    inline for (@typeInfo(modules).Struct.decls) |decl, i| {
        const module = @field(modules, decl.name);
        log.info("i {d}", .{i});
        try module.main();
    }
}
```

And the neat thing here is that, indeed, the compiler is able to eagerly fetch all 5 of those files and kick-start the compilation process, even before running the compile-time code to determine which one actually gets imported. Win-win.